# I am trying to clone a github code through git bash. When I try writing the following code it shows Command not found

Tags: python

```
madhu@LAPTOP-7CLC93GT MINGW64 ~/rasa-sample-nlu-bot (master)
$ python3 -m venv venv
bash: python3: command not found
```

This is version 3.8.4 python that I'm using right now. Previously I had python 3.7 that had two stubs already made in the manage app execution aliases that I have already turned off. Now, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: why git, git-bas or rasa tag ?
You just need to install python3

Comment: because I'm doing this on gitbash

Comment: "Gitbash" is a port of bash to Windows, done because Git needs a Unix-style shell. It has nothing to do with Git itself, it's just bash for Windows instead of bash for Linux or Solaris or whatever. In any case, however you went about installing Python 3, this did not put a `python3` command into whatever you are setting as your `$PATH` in bash. This could be because your `$PATH` is missing something, or because the Python 3 installation merely installed Python 3 as the `python` command, not as `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed python, then you have to install python3 in order to use this command in git bash

In the case, you already installed Python then you will have to check the PATH environment variable of your machine.

Comment: I have already installed python3 on my pc.

Comment: can you please tell me what i should specifically check on path environment variable?

Comment: I think you can follow this post: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-python-to-windows-path/